# pdoResources сортировка по значению tv

Tags: modx, revo

Создал дополнительное поле с названием "**Column**" (radio), с возможными значениями:

```
Первая колонка==firstColumn||Вторая колонка==secondColumn
```

На странице сайта планируется в первую колонку выводить материалы, помеченные **firstColumn**, а во вторую, соответственно, **secondColumn**.

В шаблоне страницы делаю вывод для первой колонки:

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &parents=`13`
    &tpl=`myTpl`
    &processTVs=`1`
    &includeTVs=`firstColumn`
]]
```

Подскажите, что нужно сделать дальше, чтобы выводились только материалы, помеченные как **firstColumn**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `includeTVs` нужно добавлять название тв, а не его значение:

```
&includeTVs=`Column`
```

А чтобы отфильтровать ресурсы по значению этого тв надо воспользоваться параметром `tvFilters`

```
&tvFilters=`Column==firstColumn`
```

Comment: Благодарю, Vasis! У меня была ошибка, из-за которой ресурсы не отображались, когда всё было сделано правильно. Когда исправил её, ваш ответ помог мне настроить отображение.